# bootstrap affix not working properly with firefox

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have a left sidebar in my rails application that uses bootstrap affix. I have set up this bootply to share my approach:

http://www.bootply.com/mwg1ZEM8zh

It works just like wanted with Chrome, but with Firefox affix stops working everytime I follow a link (the sidebar is in every page of my app). If I refresh the page affix starts working again. I have used data attributes to add the affix behavior, no javascript at all. Should I use javascript? Am I doing something else wrong?

I am using bootstrap 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using javascript as well and now it works with Firefox as well.

```
<script>
  $('.sidebar').affix();
</script>
```